# Out-parameters and move semantics

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

Consider a case of a lock-free concurrent data structure where a `pop()` operation needs to return an item or `false` if the cointainer is empty (rather than blocking or throwing). The data structure is templated on a user type `T`, which can potentially be large (but also could be lightweight, and I want things to be efficient in either case). `T` has to be at least movable, but I don't want it to have to be copyable.

I was thinking that the function signature would be `bool DS<T>::pop(T &item)` so the item is extracted as an out-parameter rather than return value (which instead is used to indicate success or failure). However, how do I actually pass it out? Assume there's an underlying buffer. Would I do `item = std::move(_buff[_tail])`—does it make sense to move into a reference out-parameter? A downside is that the user would have to pass in a default-constructed T, which goes a bit against effective RAII because the result is an object that hasn't actually initialized its resources if the function fails.

Another option is returning an `std::pair<bool, T>` rather than using an out-parameter, but there again needs to be a default-constructible `T` which holds no resource in the case of failure, for the `return std::make_pair(false, T)`.

A third option would be returning the item as `std::unique_ptr<T>`, but this incurs useless overhead in the case of `T` being a pointer or another lightweight type. While I could store just pointers in the data structure with the actual items stored externally, that incurs not just the penalty of additional dereferences and cache misses, but also removes the natural padding that items stored directly in the buffer add and help minimize producer and consumer threads from hitting the same cache lines.

Comment: This is what `boost::optional`, and soon `std::optional`, are for.

Comment: You can return a storage which may or may not contain an object, using `std::aligned_storage`. That's basically what `std::optional` is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <string>

template<class T>
struct atomic_queue
{
    using value_type = T;

    auto pop() -> boost::optional<T>
    {
        boost::optional<T> result;

        /*
         * insert atomic ops here, optionally filling result
         */

        return result;
    };

    auto push(T&& arg) -> bool
    {

        /*
         * insert atomic ops here, optionally stealing arg
         */

        return true;
    };

    static auto make_empty_result() {
        return boost::optional<T>();
    }

};

struct difficult {
    difficult(std::string);
    difficult() = delete;
    difficult(difficult const&) = delete;
    difficult& operator=(difficult const&) = delete;
    difficult(difficult &&) = default;
    difficult& operator=(difficult &&) = default;
};

extern void spin();

int main()
{
    atomic_queue<difficult> q;

    auto d = difficult("arg");
    while(not q.push(std::move(d)))
        spin();

    auto popped = q.make_empty_result();
    while(not (popped = q.pop()))
        spin();

    auto& val = popped.get();
}
```